# Add GIF to Swift Playground

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gif, swift-playground

I have an SKScene in a Swift Playground and I want to add this gif (https://media.giphy.com/media/uMU6E2DFqeZSE/giphy.gif) to the background as an SKSpriteNode. I first tried converting it as an animated UIImage into an SKSpriteNode as shown below:

```
let dance = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("macarenadance.gif", duration: 3.0)
let texture = SKTexture(image: dance!)
let testImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
scene.addChild(testImage)
```

But it encountered a conversion error and stopped midway through running. It seems as it's not possible to use an animated UIImage as a sprite. Any suggestions/alternatives to displaying the gif in the Swift Playground would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

UIImage unfortunately does not support gif animation, but luckily enough, there is 3rd party library to help you out.

It's called [SwiftGif](https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift).

Below is the example usage. Add the file to the source of the playground and paste this in:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport



let image = UIImage.gif(name: "yourgifgoeshere.gif")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

Comment: The `imageView` can be set like this: `let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use separated images for SKTextureAnimations:

```
   let texture = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "macarenadance0.png")
   let texture1 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "macarenadance1.png")
   let texture2 = SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "macarenadance2.png")

    let textures = [texture,texture1,texture2]

    let testImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture);

    testImage.run(SKAction.repeatForever(
       SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.3)))
   addChild(testImage)
```